# Error while using cmake install for sphero_ros

Tags: catkin-make, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to install sphero_ros following the instructions given here (I'm sorry I can't publish links. They are present at github mmwise sphere)
I get the following error when I do `catkin_make install`

```
error: option --install-layout not recognized
CMake Error at sphero_ros/sphero_driver/catkin_generated/safe_execute_install.cmake:4 (message):
```

Please help me overcome this:

P.S.:The complete trace is:

```
shahensha@shahensha:~/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero$ catkin_make install
Base path: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero
Source space: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/src
Build space: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build
Devel space: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/devel
Install space: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make install -j8 -l8" in "/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] [100%] [100%] Built target sphero_node_generate_messages_cpp
Built target sphero_node_generate_messages_py
Built target sphero_node_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] Built target sphero_node_generate_messages
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/.catkin
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/_setup_util.py
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/env.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/setup.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/setup.sh
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/setup.zsh
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/.rosinstall
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/lib/pkgconfig/sphero_bringup.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_bringup/cmake/sphero_bringupConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_bringup/cmake/sphero_bringupConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_bringup/package.xml
-- Installing: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_bringup/launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_bringup/launch/sphero.launch
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/lib/pkgconfig/sphero_description.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/cmake/sphero_descriptionConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/cmake/sphero_descriptionConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/package.xml
-- Installing: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/meshes
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/meshes/SpheroModel.dae
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/meshes/Sphero_Textured.dae
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/meshes/Sphero.dae
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/meshes/SpheroTexture.jpg
-- Installing: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/urdf
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_description/urdf/sphero.urdf
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/lib/pkgconfig/sphero_driver.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_driver/cmake/sphero_driverConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_driver/cmake/sphero_driverConfig-version.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/share/sphero_driver/package.xml
+ [ -n  ]
+ cd /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/src/sphero_ros/sphero_driver
+ /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/share/pyshared: CATKIN_BINARY_DIR=/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build /home/shahensha/Development/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/src/sphero_ros/sphero_driver/setup.py build --build-base /home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build/sphero_ros/sphero_driver install --install-layout=deb --prefix=/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install --install-scripts=/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/install/bin
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --install-layout not recognized
CMake Error at sphero_ros/sphero_driver/catkin_generated/safe_execute_install.cmake:4 (message):
  
  execute_process(/home/shahensha/Development/RobotSim/Python/Sphero/build/sphero_ros/sphero_driver/catkin_generated/python_distutils_install.sh)
  returned error code
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sphero_ros/sphero_driver/cmake_install.cmake:51 (INCLUDE)
  cmake_install.cmake:132 (INCLUDE)


make: *** [install] Error 1
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82776/error-while-using-cmake-install-for-sphero_ros/) by [shahensha](https://answers.ros.org/users/7021/shahensha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like your `setup.py` is not taking the `--install-layout` option. This might be related to your Setuptools or Distribute Python modules. Can you check what versions of those you have? What OS are you using?

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0